# Resynthesizer GIMP 2.10/14 Windows vs Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: gimp

Managed to copy the necessary files to the plugins directory in Windows, and the resynthesizer tools work in Windows.

My question is, why is it so un-godly difficult to do the same thing in Linux and should it really be that way.

I'm running GIMP 2.10.14 on both platforms, but the Linux side of things is impossible, why is that ?

In Windows, all I had to do was copy the plugin scripts to the proper directory and presto, all is working.

This is not the case with Linux, and for the life in me I cannot understand why that would be so ?

Is there a real reason why this is the case ?

Comment: `sudo apt install gimp-plugin-registry` provides you with this and other plugins in a way that beats Windows in ease of use and security.

Answer (score 0):

Because in Ubuntu, someone suddenly made the Gimp python support optional. If you have it, there is a `Python-fu` entry near the bottom of the Filters menu, and a few things that use Python scripts start working.

So make sure you installed the `gimp-python` package from the repos.

Comment: Alas, the `gimp-python` package is no longer there. I do not really understand it, as python2 is working correctly on my kubuntu 20.04.

Comment: @kay_D https://www.gimp-forum.net/Thread-Heal-Selection-Missing-from-Gimp-on-Ubuntu-20-04?pid=18351#pid18351

Comment: Thanks, @xenoid , I tried #5 on that forum, plus I installed python-is-python2 (not sure if that is necessary), and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest solution is to install the appimage version of Gimp https://appimage.github.io/GIMP/

An alternative answer is in the thread linked to by xenoid it works with the **deb version of GIMP 2.10.18** in Ubuntu 20.04 (there are also snap and flatpack versions).  What this does is to install the missing python integration by adding files from Ubuntu 18.10.

["heal selection missing GIMP ubuntu"](https://www.gimp-forum.net/Thread-Heal-Selection-Missing-from-Gimp-on-Ubuntu-20-04?pid=18351#pid18351)

```
sudo apt install python2.7

sudo apt install python python-cairo python-gobject-2

wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pygtk/python-gtk2_2.24.0-6_amd64.deb

wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gimp/gimp-python_2.10.8-2_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

In addition you should install the plugins.

```
sudo apt install gimp-plugin-registry
```

[Thanks to xenoid.](https://askubuntu.com/a/1203685/22949)